# How to forward T to function taking const &T as an argument

Tags: templates, c++11

I want to be able to call arbitrary functions with arguments packed in variant class that is not in my control (let's call it `blackbox`). I have written a function template `unpack<T>` which extracts value from `blackbox` that needs to be specialized for target types. This works fine for arguments passed by value. However, I have no idea how to handle pass-by reference:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

/* Variant container */
struct blackbox
{
    int int_value() const { return 42; }
    bool bool_value() const { return true; }
    std::string string_value() const { return "str"; }
};

/* Unpack function templates */
template<typename T>
T unpack(const blackbox &v)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "This template has to be specialized");
}

template<>
int unpack(const blackbox &v)
{
    return v.int_value();
}

template<>
bool unpack(const blackbox &v)
{
    return v.bool_value();
}

template<>
std::string unpack(const blackbox &v)
{
    return v.string_value();
}

/* Call function with arguments extracted from blackbox */
template<typename T>
void call(std::function<void(T)> f, const blackbox &v)
{
    f(unpack<T>(v));
}

/* Sample functions */

void f_int(int i) { std::cout << "f_int(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
void f_bool(bool b) { std::cout << "f_bool(" << b << ")" << std::endl; }
void f_str(std::string s) { std::cout << "f_str(" << s << ")" << std::endl; }
void f_str_ref(const std::string &s) { std::cout << "f_str_ref(" << s << ")" << std::endl; }


int main()
{
    blackbox b;

    // direct call
    f_str_ref(b.string_value());

    // indirect call
    call(std::function<void(int)>(f_int), b);
    call(std::function<void(bool)>(f_bool), b);
    call(std::function<void(std::string)>(f_str), b);
    call(std::function<void(const std::string&)>(f_str_ref), b); //doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

I need `unpack` specialization that forwards `std::string` instances to functions that take `const std::string&` argument. Defining

```
template<>
const std::string& unpack(const blackbox &v)
{
    return v.string_value();
}
```

obviously doesn't work, because reference to local variable is returned. Not defining `unpack` specialization for `const std::string&` causes static assertion to fail.

Ideally, `unpack<std::string>` should be used for `const std::string&`, but providing separate specialization would be sufficient.

Comment: did you try `f(unpack<typename std::decay<T>::type>(v));` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Your comment qualifies as an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`std::decay<T>`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay/) from [`<type_traits>`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits), that removes *cv*-qualifiers and references from given type (unless this is a function or array type):

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay<const std::string&>::type,
                           std::string>::value, "!");
```

That being said, you can use the following syntax:

```
f(unpack<typename std::decay<T>::type>(v));
```

so that any variation of [cv/`&`/`&&`] `std::string` type will evaluate to plain `std::string`.